# How to extend an attribute directive to update a data model?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm currently using this directive called [angular-multiple-selection](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-multiple-selection) which is great (and the only one of its kind that I can find) but it doesn't seem to provide a list of selected elements after the event has fired.  I need to update my model after selecting one or more elements and then have the model update the directive as well.

[Here's a plucker demonstrating the issue.](https://plnkr.co/edit/wZbkhNwc7LNdGYGSW6F0?p=preview)

**INDEX.HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

  <head>
    <script src="https://opensource.keycdn.com/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="directive.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />

    <script id="content-template" type="text/ng-template">
      <h4>Lasso, click or [Shift] + click to select fields</h4>
      <div class="item_container" multiple-selection-zone>
          <div ng-repeat="f in model.transaction.fields" multiple-selection-item class="well" ng-class="{'selecting': isSelecting ,'selected': isSelected}">{{f.label}}</div>
      </div>
      <h4>I need the data model "selected" properties below to update when the related field is selected above.</h4>
      <pre>{{model | json}}</pre>
      <h4>And then when the data model updates, I need the directive to update the selected fields appropriately as well (i.e. using the select/deselect all buttons below).</h4>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="model.selectAll()">Select All</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="model.deselectAll()">Deselect All</button>
    </script>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <content-component></content-component>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

**SCRIPT.JS**

```
console.clear();

function contentController(TransactionFactory) {
  var model = this;
  model.transaction = TransactionFactory;

  model.selectAll = function() {
    //mark all fields as selected
    for (var i = 0; i < model.transaction.fields.length; i++) {
      model.transaction.fields[i].selected = true;
    }
  }

  model.deselectAll = function() {
    //deselect all fields that are selected
    for (var i = 0; i < model.transaction.fields.length; i++) {
      model.transaction.fields[i].selected = false;
    }
  }
}

var app = angular.module("app", ['multipleSelection']);

app.factory('TransactionFactory', function () {
    var transaction = {
        fields: [
          {label: "field 1", selected: false}, 
          {label: "field 2", selected: false}, 
          {label: "field 3", selected: false}, 
          {label: "field 4", selected: false}, 
          {label: "field 5", selected: false}
        ]
    };
    return transaction;
});

app.component("contentComponent", {
    template: $("#content-template").html(),
    controllerAs: "model",
    controller: ["TransactionFactory", contentController]
});
```

**DIRECTIVE.JS**

```
/**
 * Angular JS multiple-selection module
 * @author Maksym Pomazan
 * @version 0.0.3
 * https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-multiple-selection
 */
function getSelectableElements(element) {
    var out = [];
    var childs = element.children();
    for (var i = 0; i < childs.length; i++) {
        var child = angular.element(childs[i]);
        if (child.scope().isSelectable) {
            out.push(child);
        } else {
            if (child.scope().$id!=element.scope().$id && child.scope().isSelectableZone === true) {

            } else {
                out = out.concat(getSelectableElements(child));
            }
        }
    }
    return out;
}

function offset(element) {
    var documentElem,
        box = {
            top: 0,
            left: 0
        },
        doc = element && element.ownerDocument;
    documentElem = doc.documentElement;

    if (typeof element.getBoundingClientRect !== undefined) {
        box = element.getBoundingClientRect();
    }

    return {
        top: box.top + (window.pageYOffset || documentElem.scrollTop) - (documentElem.clientTop || 0),
        left: box.left + (window.pageXOffset || documentElem.scrollLeft) - (documentElem.clientLeft || 0)
    };
}

angular.module('multipleSelection', [])
    .directive('multipleSelectionItem', [function() {
        return {
            scope: true,
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function(scope, element, iAttrs, controller) {

                scope.isSelectable = true;
                scope.isSelecting = false;
                scope.isSelected = false;

                element.on('mousedown', function(event) {
                    if (element.scope().isSelected) {
                        if (event.ctrlKey) {
                            element.scope().isSelected = false;
                            element.scope().$apply();
                        }
                    } else {
                        if (!event.ctrlKey) {
                            var childs = getSelectableElements(element.parent());
                            for (var i = 0; i < childs.length; i++) {
                                if (childs[i].scope().isSelectable) {
                                    if (childs[i].scope().isSelecting === true || childs[i].scope().isSelected === true) {
                                        childs[i].scope().isSelecting = false;
                                        childs[i].scope().isSelected = false;
                                        childs[i].scope().$apply();
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        element.scope().isSelected = true;
                        element.scope().$apply();

                    }
                    event.stopPropagation();
                });
            }
        };
    }])
    .directive('multipleSelectionZone', ['$document', function($document) {
        return {
            scope: true,
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function(scope, element, iAttrs, controller) {

                scope.isSelectableZone = true;

                var startX = 0,
                    startY = 0;
                var helper;

                /**
                 * Check that 2 boxes hitting
                 * @param  {Object} box1
                 * @param  {Object} box2
                 * @return {Boolean} is hitting
                 */
                function checkElementHitting(box1, box2) {
                    return (box2.beginX <= box1.beginX && box1.beginX <= box2.endX || box1.beginX <= box2.beginX && box2.beginX <= box1.endX) &&
                        (box2.beginY <= box1.beginY && box1.beginY <= box2.endY || box1.beginY <= box2.beginY && box2.beginY <= box1.endY);
                }

                /**
                 * Transform box to object to:
                 *  beginX is always be less then endX
                 *  beginY is always be less then endY
                 * @param  {Number} startX
                 * @param  {Number} startY
                 * @param  {Number} endX
                 * @param  {Number} endY
                 * @return {Object} result Transformed object
                 */
                function transformBox(startX, startY, endX, endY) {

                    var result = {};

                    if (startX > endX) {
                        result.beginX = endX;
                        result.endX = startX;
                    } else {
                        result.beginX = startX;
                        result.endX = endX;
                    }
                    if (startY > endY) {
                        result.beginY = endY;
                        result.endY = startY;
                    } else {
                        result.beginY = startY;
                        result.endY = endY;
                    }
                    return result;
                }

                /**
                 * Method move selection helper
                 * @param  {Element} hepler
                 * @param  {Number} startX
                 * @param  {Number} startY
                 * @param  {Number} endX
                 * @param  {Number} endY
                 */
                function moveSelectionHelper(hepler, startX, startY, endX, endY) {

                    var box = transformBox(startX, startY, endX, endY);

                    helper.css({
                        "top": box.beginY + "px",
                        "left": box.beginX + "px",
                        "width": (box.endX - box.beginX) + "px",
                        "height": (box.endY - box.beginY) + "px"
                    });
                }


                /**
                 * Method on Mouse Move
                 * @param  {Event} @event
                 */
                function mousemove(event) {
                    // Prevent default dragging of selected content
                    event.preventDefault();
                    // Move helper
                    moveSelectionHelper(helper, startX, startY, event.pageX, event.pageY);
                    // Check items is selecting
                    var childs = getSelectableElements(element);
                    for (var i = 0; i < childs.length; i++) {
                        if (checkElementHitting(transformBox(offset(childs[i][0]).left, offset(childs[i][0]).top, offset(childs[i][0]).left + childs[i].prop('offsetWidth'), offset(childs[i][0]).top + childs[i].prop('offsetHeight')), transformBox(startX, startY, event.pageX, event.pageY))) {
                            if (childs[i].scope().isSelecting === false) {
                                childs[i].scope().isSelecting = true;
                                childs[i].scope().$apply();
                            }
                        } else {
                            if (childs[i].scope().isSelecting === true) {
                                childs[i].scope().isSelecting = false;
                                childs[i].scope().$apply();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }



                /**
                 * Event on Mouse up
                 * @param  {Event} event
                 */
                function mouseup(event) {
                    // Prevent default dragging of selected content
                    event.preventDefault();
                    // Remove helper
                    helper.remove();
                    // Change all selecting items to selected
                    var childs = getSelectableElements(element);

                    for (var i = 0; i < childs.length; i++) {
                        if (childs[i].scope().isSelecting === true) {
                            childs[i].scope().isSelecting = false;

                            childs[i].scope().isSelected = event.ctrlKey ? !childs[i].scope().isSelected : true;
                            childs[i].scope().$apply();
                        } else {
                            if (checkElementHitting(transformBox(childs[i].prop('offsetLeft'), childs[i].prop('offsetTop'), childs[i].prop('offsetLeft') + childs[i].prop('offsetWidth'), childs[i].prop('offsetTop') + childs[i].prop('offsetHeight')), transformBox(event.pageX, event.pageY, event.pageX, event.pageY))) {
                                if (childs[i].scope().isSelected === false) {
                                    childs[i].scope().isSelected = true;
                                    childs[i].scope().$apply();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    // Remove listeners
                    $document.off('mousemove', mousemove);
                    $document.off('mouseup', mouseup);
                }

                element.on('mousedown', function(event) {
                    // Prevent default dragging of selected content
                    event.preventDefault();
                    if (!event.ctrlKey) {
                        // Skip all selected or selecting items
                        var childs = getSelectableElements(element);
                        for (var i = 0; i < childs.length; i++) {
                            if (childs[i].scope().isSelecting === true || childs[i].scope().isSelected === true) {
                                childs[i].scope().isSelecting = false;
                                childs[i].scope().isSelected = false;
                                childs[i].scope().$apply();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    // Update start coordinates
                    startX = event.pageX;
                    startY = event.pageY;
                    // Create helper
                    helper = angular
                        .element("<div></div>")
                        .addClass('select-helper');

                    $document.find('body').eq(0).append(helper);
                    // Attach events
                    $document.on('mousemove', mousemove);
                    $document.on('mouseup', mouseup);
                });
            }
        };
    }]);
```

**STYLE.CSS**

```
body {margin-top: 30px;}

.blue { background-color: blue; color: white; }

.red { background-color: red; color: white; }

/*=============== UPDATED ===============*/

.item_container {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
    /* disable selection */

    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    cursor: crosshair;
}

.item_container div:hover {
    background-color: yellow;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.item_container div.selected:hover {
    background-color: darkgreen;
}

.item_container div {
    width: 50%
}

.select-helper {
    position: absolute;
    border: 1px dashed red;
    background: red;
    opacity: 0.2;
}

.selected {
    background-color: green;
    color: white;
}

.selecting {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

Comment: multiple select is supported by the built in Angular `select` directive already; the only thing I can see that this directive does is allow lasso selection.  beyond that, this directive has 5 issues in it's github page, and 3 of them are asking for the feature that you are asking about here.  It seems like this directive wasn't written for what you want to do in mind, and trying to make this operate more like the built in `select multiple` would be quite a chore.

Comment: @Claies Do you have a link for the Angular `select` directive?  All I can find is stuff for HTML select elements.

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select.  basically if you add `ng-model` to a select HTML element, angular will load the `select` directive over top of it automatically.

Comment: @Claies Oh right - yeah, that's a select HTML element. Mine are just multiple div elements (representing form fields on a PDF) scattered around using absolute positioning so I don't think I can use that.

Comment: hmmm, ok, that makes things more complex;  one way to solve this might be to use `ng-click` to call a function that changes the `selected` value, but that wouldn't work on the lasso select.

Comment: Yeah, I might have to ditch the lasso thing and just try to do the ng-click.  I'm not sure that solves things in the opposite direction, though, using the Select/Deselect buttons.  Of course, without the lasso, I can probably just ditch the directive altogether and just change the model on click instead.

Comment: I've started to experiment with the code of that directive;  I might have a fork of it that has some additional features soon....